# How do I add users to allow ssh tunneling access?

Tags: linux

I'm running Cent OS 5.6, I've disabled ssh tunnelling for everyone, but I need to know how to enable it for specific users.

Comment: Please clarify how you disabled ssh tunneling. Did you do `PermitTunnel no` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully someone can come up with a better answer, but here's something that would work: Start a second sshd daemon on some other port, say 222. In this second sshd daemon, enable tunneling, but use the `AllowUsers` or `AllowGroups` options to only allow your specific users to be able to tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

Use a "Match" statement in the sshd config can be used with a user or a group to enable or disable specific options.

In centos/rhel, there is an example at the bottom of the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.

```
# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
Match User anoncvs
       X11Forwarding no
       AllowTcpForwarding no
       ForceCommand cvs server
```